# move across the same distance of a curve at increasing speeds

Tags: java, math

I have an object that I am trying to get to move in a smooth "arc". The x value of the object does not actually change, but the y value does. 
The y value starts at -108, and needs to get to -37.5. Every iteration I want it to move the same distance in a shorter time. The issue is that it needs to decelerate and stop at -37.5 (this would be for half of the motion). When the current code runs the time stays the same, the distance increases. this does work for the first iteration.

This is what I have:

```
private void jump() {
    int startV = 10;
    float yVal;
    float velocity;
    int airTime = 1;
    float currY = -108;

    Main main = New Main();

    // main.iter is the iteration
    velocity = startV * (1 + (main.iter / 10)); 

    while (airtime != 0) {
        yVal = yVal + velocity;
        velocity = velocity - (1 + (main.iter / 10));

        if (currY < yVal) {
            airtime++;
        }
        else {
            airtime--;
        }
    }
    yVal = -108;
}
```

EDIT:
main.iter is an int that increments by one

Comment: What is main.iter? Is it an `int`, `double`, `Random`...?

Comment: it is an int. that increments by one.

Comment: Could you rearrange the code? You can't have access (private, public, etc.) modifiers inside a method. It isn't clear if `Main main` is inside the method or elsewhere.

Comment: So main.iter is essentially the time variable?

Comment: Yes it is controlled my the Main() function.

Comment: So you have something in `Main` that increases time by the same amount each iteration, but you want to increase time by a smaller amount each iteration, is that correct?

Comment: I guess I should have looked at the comment closer. main.iter increments by 1 every time the a loop in Main() runs. When this happens, the whole visual side of the program speeds up. Because of this when I call jump() I want to move the same, but in a shorter amount of time.